# Using a struct to store a reference to a non-Copy value

Tags: struct, reference, rust

I need an object that contains a reference to a process child and enables me to execute functions on it.

```
pub struct Shell {
    child: std::process::Child,
}

impl Shell {
    pub fn init() -> Shell {
        let mut cmd = std::process::Command::new("Command");
        let process = cmd.spawn();
        let new = Shell {
            child: process.unwrap(),
        };
        new
    }

    pub fn f1(mut self) {
        //do something with self
    }

    pub fn f2(mut self) {
        {
            let stdin = self.child.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
        }
        let output = self.child.wait_with_output();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut shell = Shell::init();
    shell.f1();
    shell.f2();
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `shell`
  --> src/main.rs:28:5
   |
27 |     shell.f1();
   |     ----- value moved here
28 |     shell.f2();
   |     ^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `shell` has type `Shell`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

[>Try it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=15c6d6d6de6a3a403e56e783e022d6c7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

The problem is that when I initialize my object, I can call functions on the object only once, because the value is moved on the first call due to standard Rust behaviour.

A simple `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` does not work here, because [`std::process::Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) does not seem to implement the `Copy` trait. Is there a way to circumvent that or wrap it into something copy-able?

#### Test Implementations

When using a mutable reference as the function argument, the initial problem appears to be solved, however, it is then not possible to access the `self.child` more than once.

```
pub struct Shell {
    child: std::process::Child,
}

impl Shell {
    pub fn init() -> Shell {
        let mut cmd = std::process::Command::new("Command");
        let process = cmd.spawn();
        let new = Shell {
            child: process.unwrap(),
        };
        new
    }

    pub fn f1(&mut self) {
        //do something with self
    }

    pub fn f2(&mut self) {
        {
            let stdin = self.child.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
        }
        let output = self.child.wait_with_output();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut shell = Shell::init();
    shell.f1();
    shell.f2();
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:21:22
   |
21 |         let output = self.child.wait_with_output();
   |                      ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

[>Try it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d97112e2ddaf5a57fb873450417a5aa1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Is there a way to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `self.child` has to be consumed by `wait_with_output()`. This is why `self` must not be passed to `f2` by reference, but by value:

```
pub struct Shell {
    child: std::process::Child,
}

impl Shell {
    pub fn init() -> Shell {
        let mut cmd = std::process::Command::new("Command");
        let process = cmd.spawn();
        let new = Shell {
            child: process.unwrap(),
        };
        new
    }

    pub fn f1(&mut self) {
        //do something with self
    }

    pub fn f2(mut self) {
        {
            let stdin = self.child.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
        }
        let output = self.child.wait_with_output();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut shell = Shell::init();
    shell.f1();
    shell.f2();
}
```

[>Try it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f3e4888f62d9ab6f347ef24394c65a49&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

However this implies that `f2` must be the last function that accesses `self.child`.